# Decoded JSON Doesn't Recognized As An Array in usort()

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this code :-

```
$category = json_decode($row['product_cat'], true);

usort($category, "cmp");
```

and it produces this error message :

> PHP Warning:  usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   /home/user/public_html/cron/test.php on line 22

why `$category` in `usort()` parameter is not recognized as an array? in fact, that's an array decoded from json. anybody knows why this error message appears? thank you.

here's my full code :

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['id'], $b['id']);
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $category = json_decode($row['product_cat'], true);

    usort($category, "cmp");

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($category);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: can you show output of `var_dump($row['product_cat']);` (i don't think it's json right now and that's why you are getting error). i think it's a string containing single or comma seperated id's

Comment: @AlivetoDie : string(30) "[{"id":"1","value":"Console"}]" string(67) "[{"id":"18","value":"Games"},{"id":"36","value":"Nintendo Switch"}]"

Comment: that's `var_dump`

Comment: whats the output of var_dump($category); before your usort line?

Comment: this seems correct then. ok do like this:- `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $category = json_decode($row['product_cat'], true);
    
    if(is_array($category) && count($category)>1){
  usort($category, "cmp");
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($category);
    echo '</pre>';
}
`

Comment: @Saint Robson : please check $row['product_cat'] is given valid json or not. please check using this link https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Please check $category  is not empty before call usort.

Comment: @AlivetoDie : array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["value"]=> string(7) "Console" } }

Comment: @AlivetoDie : that is output of `echo '<pre>'; print_r($category); echo '</pre>'; `

Comment: @AlivetoDie : yes. the error is gone now. thank you so much. but why? isn't decoded JSON always an array?

Comment: @SaintRobson  it seems that some-time json not coming as valid, so `json_decode` gave null and hense usort provide error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json` data you shown seems correct, but as we can't gaurentee  that all json coming in while loop is correct, we have to change code in a way that error will not occur anyhow.So do like below:-

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
   $category = json_decode($row['product_cat'], true);
   // check decode give array properly
   if(is_array($category) && count($category)>1){
      usort($category, "cmp"); 
   } 
   echo '<pre>'; print_r($category); echo '</pre>'; 
}
```

Note:-

I din't compare it will `null` directly because if suppose array is coming correctly but it have only one value in it, then `usort($category, "cmp");` call will happen unnecessarly (because there is nothing to sort).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put if condition before you usort call because some times proper json not coming in your input so json decode return null value.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['id'], $b['id']);
}

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $category = json_decode($row['product_cat'], true);
    if(isset($category) && !empty($category)){
        usort($category, "cmp");
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($category);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```